# Prevent concurrent execution of trigger function (in Postgres)

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table of (financial) transactions related to accounts. For each INSERT a trigger function gets executed that does calculations based on the previous transaction of the corresponding account.

How do I prevent concurrent executions for the same account? Each entry must only have one successor. If two INSERTs for the same account happen at the exact same time I guess both would grab the same "previous row" causing the chain of transactions to split up.

I'm thinking of introducing a "predecessor" column with a UNIQUE KEY so that while one of the two concurrent INSERTs will fail, at least the data will be correct. Is there a way to make one transaction wait on the other instead?

Comment: The issue is less invalid data than a potential deadlock.

Comment: There is only one resource (the previous row) parallel functions might wait for, how can that become a deadlock?

Comment: . . I don't know what is happening in the database.  But transaction prevent the problem you are specifically referring to.  Deadlocks are another issue.

Answer (score 0):

No. Trigger is a transaction and will not have concurrent issue. So it will run in the order as

```
Transaction {
insert of A
-- trigger of the insert of A
}

Transaction {
insert of B
-- trigger of the insert of B
}
```

In the trigger the NEW record means what has been inserted in the transaction and will not be what is inserted in another transaction.

Comment: The trigger functions run in transactions, ok. But transactions can run in parallel. If the isolation level is not "SERIALIZABLE", I don't see any reason why those two transactions should not read the same previous row.